# same blob in sqlite return?

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I set one image for every id in my database but only got the first row blob !

this is my database.java :

```
public byte[] getpic(int id) {
        Cursor cu = mydb.rawQuery("select * from content where ID=" + id, null);
        cu.moveToFirst();
        byte s[] = cu.getBlob(cu.getColumnIndex("IMAGE"));
        return s;
    }
```

in main.java

```
private void load(String sea, String Name, int page3) {

        db.open();



        byte[] p = db.getpic(page3);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);

        db.close();

    }
```

what should i do???

Comment: what you want actually?

Comment: @MD    i make a book and every story has its own picture. but when i click on every story just the first story image display.

Comment: because in your code, You move your cursor on top and that execute only one time because there is no for loop.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani what should i do exactly?

Comment: check you have store same image for every row?? or different image

Comment: You're using the wrong ID.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i check it and i have seperate images

Comment: @CL. i think i adress the wrong id to load . but dont know how to fix it